# how to know if first app launch after update from appstore

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, app-store

I have a version 1.0 on appstore.
I have just got version 1.1 approved for appstore.

When the app on version 1.0 is updated from appstore, there is a crash on the device. but when we download a fresh version of version 1.1, the app doesn't crash.

How can I test this using Xcode?
Please help.

Comment: Are you using coredata and have you done any changes to the data model in that?

Comment: no Coredata. But yes I have made changes with user defaults after that. added more key value pairs. But that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 1):

Install your first version application to device through Xcode.

Then  install your second version application to the same device through Xcode (**Note**: Don't delete the previous installed version from your device).

So it will not overwrite the app contends which will be available in your Library or Document Directory.

Then it will crash.. so you can get it the reason through Xcode console.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem in your save files?

When in device with app 1.0 user will update to 1.1, then a folders Library/Caches, Library/Preferences, will stay.

When user is redownload a fresh 1.1 version, it seems this folder will be a empty.

For test him, try run 1.0 and after some operations in app, try to update to 1.1 over 1.0. If crash in app, XCode must catch him